# random color of the figure. canvas. javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a task to apply random color to the rectangle every time when it starts moving down from the top. now it works correctly with the exception of first iteration as the rectangle has black(default) background color. so how to apply random color to the rectangle from the very first time?

```js
var currentPos = 0;

function animate() {  
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth); 
  ctx.fillRect(100, currentPos, 20, 20);
  currentPos += 1;
  if(currentPos >= canvas.clientHeight) {
    currentPos = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
  } 

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
}

document.body.onload = animate;
```

```html
<doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas {        
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="200" height="180" id="canvas"></canvas>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set the fill style before you draw the first rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var currentPos = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';

function animate() {  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth); 
  ctx.fillRect(100, currentPos, 20, 20);
  currentPos += 1;
  if(currentPos >= canvas.clientHeight) {
    currentPos = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
  } 

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
}

document.body.onload = animate;
```

```html
<doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas {        
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="200" height="180" id="canvas"></canvas>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to implement in my code but have an error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"

Comment: I have solved already. just move script tag in the end of the body. after canvas tag